# Testimonial Slider not working properly using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add this testimonial slider to my site but it is not displaying properly! It looks like this:
[image]

```css
#testimonial4{
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 375px;
  position: relative;
  background: #1583c9;
}
#testimonial4 .carousel-inner{
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}
#testimonial4 .carousel-inner:hover{
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
#testimonial4 .carousel-inner:active{
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
#testimonial4 .carousel-inner .item{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators{
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: e-resize;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators li{
  padding: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 2px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators .active{
  padding: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin: 2px 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators::-webkit-scrollbar{
  height: 3px;
}
.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background: #eeeeee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control{
  top: 175px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 40px;
  bottom: auto;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.3,1,0,1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.3,1,0,1);
}
.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left{
  left: 7%;
  right: auto;
}
.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right{
  right: 7%;
  left: auto;
}
.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left:hover,
.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right:hover{
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.testimonial4_header{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 550px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.testimonial4_header h4{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testimonial4_slide{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.testimonial4_slide img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.testimonial4_slide p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
}

.testimonial4_slide h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control{
    display: none;
  }
  .testimonial4_header{
    width: 95%;
  }
  .testimonial4_header h4{
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .testimonial4_slide{
    width: 98%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px){
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left{
    left: 2%;
  }
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right{
    right: 2%;
  }
  .testimonial4_header{
    width: 95%;
  }
  .testimonial4_slide{
    width: 98%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left{
    left: 5%;
  }
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right{
    right: 5%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes psBoxShadowEffect_2{
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #ffffff, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 0 5px 5px #ffffff, 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes psBoxShadowEffect_2{
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #ffffff, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 0 5px 5px #ffffff, 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="testimonial4" class="carousel slide testimonial4_indicators testimonial4_control_button thumb_scroll_x swipe_x" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-interval="5000" data-duration="2000">
  <div class="testimonial4_header">
   <h4>what our clients are saying</h4>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#testimonial4" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#testimonial4" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#testimonial4" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item active">
    <div class="testimonial4_slide">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-circle img-responsive" />
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur.</p>
     <h4>Ben Hanna</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="testimonial4_slide">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-circle img-responsive" />
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur.</p>
     <h4>Ben Hanna</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="testimonial4_slide">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-circle img-responsive" />
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur.</p>
     <h4>Ben Hanna</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#testimonial4" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#testimonial4" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
 </div>
```

It was showing properly when I loaded my page for the first time. All required files are added. (bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js, popper.js, fontawesome.min.css). I have also checked this code in other browsers but the result is the same!

Comment: and how do you want it to show ?

Comment: Like this:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/O5eg8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of class of the inner carousel from `.item` to `.carousel-item`

Adding code so you can see it yourself. If it's not working for you locally, you should check your import links.

```css
#testimonial4 {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 375px;
  position: relative;
  background: #1583c9;
}

#testimonial4 .carousel-inner {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}

#testimonial4 .carousel-inner:hover {
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

#testimonial4 .carousel-inner:active {
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}

#testimonial4 .carousel-inner .item {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: e-resize;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators li {
  padding: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 2px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators .active {
  padding: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin: 2px 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 3px;
}

.testimonial4_indicators .carousel-indicators::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #eeeeee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control {
  top: 175px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 40px;
  bottom: auto;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0, 1);
}

.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left {
  left: 7%;
  right: auto;
}

.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right {
  right: 7%;
  left: auto;
}

.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left:hover,
.testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.testimonial4_header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 550px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.testimonial4_header h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testimonial4_slide {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial4_slide img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.testimonial4_slide p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
}

.testimonial4_slide h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control {
    display: none;
  }
  .testimonial4_header {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .testimonial4_header h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .testimonial4_slide {
    width: 98%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left {
    left: 2%;
  }
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right {
    right: 2%;
  }
  .testimonial4_header {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .testimonial4_slide {
    width: 98%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.left {
    left: 5%;
  }
  .testimonial4_control_button .carousel-control.right {
    right: 5%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes psBoxShadowEffect_2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #ffffff, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 5px 5px #ffffff, 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes psBoxShadowEffect_2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #ffffff, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 5px 5px #ffffff, 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<div id="testimonial4" class="carousel slide testimonial4_indicators testimonial4_control_button thumb_scroll_x swipe_x" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-interval="5000" data-duration="2000">
  <div class="testimonial4_header">
    <h4>what our clients are saying</h4>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#testimonial4" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonial4" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonial4" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="testimonial4_slide">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-circle img-responsive" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur.</p>
        <h4>Ben Hanna</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="testimonial4_slide">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-circle img-responsive" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur.</p>
        <h4>Ben Hanna</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="testimonial4_slide">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-circle img-responsive" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit am nibh unc varius facilisis eros ed erat in in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet urabitur.</p>
        <h4>Ben Hanna</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#testimonial4" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#testimonial4" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But the slider is not working. Items are not sliding.

Comment: please help?? ^^

Comment: @UmarAhsan Updated with code, not sure what the problem is.